How can I skip blank cell while using sumifs?
I want to skip blank cells in a column while summing up.
Spreadsheet 1



Column A
Column B




Sale1
2



4



Spreadsheet 2



Column A




2






The formula that I use
=SUMIFS('Spreadsheet1'!$B:$B;'SpreadSheet'!$A:$A;"<>")
But this formula doesnt work and I got Null in Spreadsheet 2 Column A.
How can I skip empty cells while summing up as shown above?
Thanks in advance for your assistance in solving this problem.
Yucel Emir

Your formula seems correct. It give me correct result =SUMIFS(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!A:A,"<>").

There are other criteria, maybe this is the reason why it is not working

Possible that cells in column A not blank rather containing something e.g. formula with result empty string

Yes you were right. The data was extracted by power query and after I applied delete to blank cells it gave me the right result.  Thanks for your comment that helped to solve the problem.

=SUMIFS(B1:B2,A1:A2,"<>") should work. If it doesn't, probably A2 is not blank, but a "blank" result from formula.
You could try =SUM((A1:A2<>"")*(B1:B2))
Result:

If this doesn't work A2 might contain spaces or other invisible characters.

You are absolutely right. So it is important to clear the formats in blank rows

You should be careful if you use Format As Table. Then you should clear the empty rows in your table. Otherwise it may remain some invisible formats that restrict to use <> function

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
